# Why me execute the same command but get different result?

Tags: mongodb

I used mongodb 2.4.10 to collect some app logs, sometimes when statistics and analysis, i execute a command, but give me different result:

```
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
86
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
47
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
47
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
47
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
47
```

the current db and collection status:

```
logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
"db" : "logs",
"collections" : 45,
"objects" : 2108341434,
"avgObjSize" : 747.0257969857837,
"dataSize" : NumberLong("1574985440052"),
"storageSize" : NumberLong("1634846926048"),
"numExtents" : 1303,
"indexes" : 230,
"indexSize" : 661429905136,
"fileSize" : NumberLong("2365305389056"),
"nsSizeMB" : 16,
"dataFileVersion" : {
    "major" : 4,
    "minor" : 5
},
"ok" : 1
}

logReplSet:PRIMARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.stats()
{
"ns" : "logs.ofapi_inf_record_20140825",
"count" : 45681275,
"size" : 45292806320,
"avgObjSize" : 991.496106884057,
"storageSize" : 47941103312,
"numExtents" : 43,
"nindexes" : 6,
"lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 1,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 18175558688,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 1482316976,
    "invokeTime_-1.0_methodName_1.0" : 7287988288,
    "uuId_1.0" : 3596499760,
    "paramValues.userCode_1.0" : 1950908064,
    "costTime_-1.0" : 2296245952,
    "exceptionMsg_1.0" : 1561599648
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Mongodb Logs: (first cost 51952ms )

Mon Sep 1 08:59:27.659 [conn5901521] command logs.$cmd command: { count: "ofapi_inf_record_20140825", query: { invokeTime:
{ $gte: "2014-08-29 19:30:52", $lte: "2014-08-29 19:41:52" }
, exceptionMsg:
{ $ne: null }
}, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1494 locks(micros) r:101254026 reslen:48 51952ms

Mon Sep 1 08:59:55.252 [conn5901521] command logs.$cmd command: { count: "ofapi_inf_record_20140825", query: { invokeTime:
{ $gte: "2014-08-29 19:30:52", $lte: "2014-08-29 19:41:52" }
, exceptionMsg:
{ $ne: null }
}, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) r:317472 reslen:48 169ms

Mon Sep 1 09:03:27.404 [conn5901521] command logs.$cmd command: { count: "ofapi_inf_record_20140825", query: { invokeTime:
{ $gte: "2014-08-29 19:30:52", $lte: "2014-08-29 19:41:52" }
, exceptionMsg:
{ $ne: null }
}, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 2 locks(micros) r:292434 reslen:48 169ms

Mon Sep 1 09:03:29.201 [conn5901521] command logs.$cmd command: { count: "ofapi_inf_record_20140825", query: { invokeTime:
{ $gte: "2014-08-29 19:30:52", $lte: "2014-08-29 19:41:52" }
, exceptionMsg:
{ $ne: null }
}, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:162235 reslen:48 162ms

Mon Sep 1 09:22:09.624 [conn5901521] command logs.$cmd command: { count: "ofapi_inf_record_20140825", query: { invokeTime:
{ $gte: "2014-08-29 19:30:52", $lte: "2014-08-29 19:41:52" }
, exceptionMsg:
{ $ne: null }
}, fields: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 281 locks(micros) r:373800 reslen:48 380ms

Additional:

1. Data is only collected, not deleted;
2. begin 2014-08-29 19:30:52 to 2014-08-29 19:41:52, no data change.
3. first i want count field("exceptionMsg") is not null, it return 47;second i count field("exceptionMsg") with regExp /Invoke remote method/, it return 37; third i count field ("exceptionMsg") with regExp /余额不足/, it return 46;

but 37 + 46 > 47, why ?

```
logReplSet:SECONDARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":{"$ne":null}})
47
logReplSet:SECONDARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":/Invoke remote method/})
37
logReplSet:SECONDARY> db.ofapi_inf_record_20140825.count({"invokeTime":{"$gte":"2014-08-29 19:30:52","$lte":"2014-08-29 19:41:52"},"exceptionMsg":/余额不足/})
46
```

Comment: Something deleted some records between your first and second requests? Like a background job?

Comment: I don't see what's so different about them? What do you expect to be the same that's different, exactly? If the results of queries are different then the state of the database is different when the queries were run, so what is happening in the system to change the state? Something that you don't expect to make meaningful differences but seems to be?

Comment: Data is only collected, not deleted; the first is return 86, but the second is 47;